# If$G$ is a group and $S \subset G$, then $\langle S \rangle$ is a normal subgroup iff $\forall g \in G$, $\forall s \in S$ $gsg^{-1} \in H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Suppose $G$ is a group, and let $S \subset G$. Let $H= \langle S \rangle$, then show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ if and only if $gsg^{-1} \in H$, $\forall g \in G, \forall s \in S$.

So first I showed that if we suppose that $H$ is a normal subgroup in $G$, then $\forall g \in G$, $\forall h \in H = \langle S \rangle$, $gsg^{-1} \in H$. But $S \subset \langle S \rangle$,  thus $\forall g \in G$, $\forall s \in S$, $gsg^{-1} \in H$.

Now how can I show the implication in other direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$H = \langle S\rangle$ means that every element of $H$ is a product of elements from $S$, and their inverses i.e. $h = s_1...s_n$, where $s_i$ is either in $S$ or the inverse of an element from $S$.

So, one way of the above  was trivial.

The other goes via the popular "conjugation trick". Suppose that $\forall s \in S, g \in G$, we have  $gsg^{-1}\in H$. Note that $(gsg^{-1})(gs^{-1}g^{-1}) = e$, so $(gs^{-1}g^{-1}) \in H$ for all $s \in S$.

Let $h \in H$. We know that $h = s_1...s_n$, where each $s_i  \in S$ or is the inverse of an element in $S$. Now,
$$
ghg^{-1} = gs_1...s_ng^{-1} = (gs_1g^{-1})(gs_2g^{-1})...(gs_ng^{-1}) \in H
$$

as each individual term is in $H$. Hence, $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g \in G$ and define $\varphi_g : H \to G$ by $\phi_g(h) = g h g^{-1}$. It is known that $\varphi_g$ is a homomorphism and from the assumption $\phi_g[S] \subseteq H$, thus $\phi_g[H] = \phi_g[ \left< S \right> ] \subseteq H$, which is what we had to prove.